# Automation Test executed by Runner works fine, but when execute this by command mvn, it gets error in test that already works fine

Tags: java, maven, testing, automation

I am a QA and created a framework(JAVA) to execute my tests. Everything is going fine running the tests by Runners. All those tests works fine and got the PASSED status, but when i tried to execute mvn clean install, all the tests started to work and get PASSED until only one test get FAILED with the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
        at steps.StepDefinitions.sistema_retorna_erro_por_informao_invalida(StepDefinitions.java:132)
        at ?.sistema retorna erro por informao
invalida(src/test/resources/features/fluxoaporteextra.feature:80)
```

To check this specific test, I isolated it using a @Tag in Features and running by Runner.java. Again the test was fine and got PASSED status.

So I isolated it the same way i did with this test to only it be tested by mvn clean install.

When i executed mvn clean install, only this test was executed and got again the same error above.

I don't know what is the difference between the ways of execute the test that occurs to take this error.

Did someone get the similar problem? Help!

Figured out this:

After check the responses and verification using sysout....i realized that the problem happens probably because the response brings a message and this message has
accentuation on some letters. When i execute the tests by Runner.java, it works fine, but when it is by mvn command the letters with accentuation dont appear in message:

response by Runner.java:

```
{
    "erro": [
        {
            "codigoErro": 44,
            "nomeErro": "Não é possivel realizar distribuição do aporte extra para este valor ",
            "descricaoErro": "Não é possivel realizar distribuição do aporte extra para este valor "
        }
    ]
}
```

response by mvn:

```
{
    "erro": [
        {
            "codigoErro": 44,
            "nomeErro": "No  possivel realizar distribuio do aporte extra para este valor ",
            "descricaoErro": "No  possivel realizar distribuio do aporte extra para este valor "
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if someone has some idea what could solve this problem, please help me.

I created a method to solve this problem, probably there is a lib that does it too, but i coulnt find:

```
public static String trataAcentuacao(String valor) {
        String[] nchar = { "ã", "õ", "á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú", "â", "ê", "î", "ô", "û", "ç", "à" };
        String[] schar ={"Ã£","Ãµ","Ã¡","Ã©","Ã­","Ã³","Ãº","Ã¢","Ãª","Ã®","Ã´","Ã»","Ã§","Ã"};
        int i = 0;
        while(i < schar.length){
            if(valor.contains(schar[i])){
                valor = valor.replace(schar[i], nchar[i]);
                }
                i++;
            }
            return valor;
        }
```

Comment: All I can say is ensure that when you execute with mvn it's using the same encoding as the IDE and the runners (likely utf-8). You

Comment: Yeah, it is the problem. I realized after some hours. I use vscode+java, but i have no idea how to check about mvn encoding. Pretty sure runners encoding is UTF-8 cuz i didnt have problems in the tests.

I tried some solution in internet but none help...so i created a method to check if the string has some of the letters not recognized and i just replace those. probably should exist some lib that does this easily, but i count find.

Comment: Mvn will use the system level default, which vs code should also use. Check your configs for both.